# How to make pair of items from a Pandas data frame column

Tags: python, pandas

We have a dataframe as follows.

```
dt1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'class': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'D']})
print(dt1)
```

We need to make a pair of "IDs" given the following rules:

- They shouldn't belong to the same class. For example (1, 7) is forbidden.
- It is also forbidden to pick items from some heterogeneous classes: "B" and "C" cannot go together.

  ```
   dt2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 5, 9], 'class1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B','D'],
              'ID2': [2, 4, 5, 8, 3, 1, 2], 'class2': ['B', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C']})
  print(dt2)
  ```

We're wondering what an efficient solution would be.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the second point? Also - show what you've got so far SO is not a free coding service. We can help, but not do the whole thing instead of you

Comment: Items from "B" and "C" can't be paired. For example, (2,6) is forbidden. Even some hints are appreciated.

Comment: But why B and C cannot, and A and D can, like where do you take the heterogeneity from?

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, suppose that only B and C are forbidden to go together. The remaining heterogeneous classes are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import numpy as np

res = dt1.assign(a=1)
res = pd.merge(res, res, on='a').drop('a', axis=1).query("(ID_x != ID_y) & (class_x != class_y)")

res['ID'] = list(np.sort(res[['ID_x', 'ID_y']].to_numpy(), axis=1))

res['class'] = list(np.sort(res[['class_x', 'class_y']].to_numpy(), axis=1))

res = res[['ID', 'class']]

res['dd'] = res['ID'].map(str)

res = res.drop_duplicates('dd').drop('dd', axis=1)
# list to exclude - keep elements ordered alpabethically
lst_to_excl = [{'A', 'B'}]

res = res.loc[~np.isin(res['class'].map(set), lst_to_excl)]
```

Outputs (as `pandas`):

```py
>>> res

        ID   class
3   [1, 4]  [A, C]
5   [1, 6]  [A, C]
7   [1, 8]  [A, D]
8   [1, 9]  [A, D]
12  [2, 4]  [B, C]
14  [2, 6]  [B, C]
16  [2, 8]  [B, D]
17  [2, 9]  [B, D]
21  [3, 4]  [A, C]
23  [3, 6]  [A, C]
25  [3, 8]  [A, D]
26  [3, 9]  [A, D]
31  [4, 5]  [B, C]
33  [4, 7]  [A, C]
34  [4, 8]  [C, D]
35  [4, 9]  [C, D]
41  [5, 6]  [B, C]
43  [5, 8]  [B, D]
44  [5, 9]  [B, D]
51  [6, 7]  [A, C]
52  [6, 8]  [C, D]
53  [6, 9]  [C, D]
61  [7, 8]  [A, D]
62  [7, 9]  [A, D]
```

**Few notes**:

1. you need to do cross join
2. you filter out base next, drop duplicates (you will have eg. (1,7) and (7,1) otherwise)
3. you filter out the "heterogeneous" ones